# How to get messages from a group chat on Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am having trouble understanding the Telethon API in Python. I have created an account and have an api_id/api_hash, but I cannot connect to the server. This is what I have:

```
chat_id = "@thecointelegraph"
api_id = 'MYID'
api_hash = 'MYHASH'

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                api_id,
                api_hash)
client.start()
```

I would like to download messages from a public telegram chat. Any help would be wonderful! Thank you!!

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your current Code? How do you know you can't connect to the Server?

Usualy you would go about it kinda like this:

```
client = TelegramClient("username", "telegram_api", "api_hash")
client.start()
messages = client.get_message_history(dialog.entity, unread)
```

At least it was like this the last time, I used Telethon, I think by get_message_history was replaced by

get_messages()

https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/messages/get_messages.html

Best thing to do is work yourself through the documentary:
https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score -2):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

entity = 'session'  # session_name
api_id = 123456
api_hash = '56bc70000yourhash'


client = TelegramClient(entity, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
```

should work